# SQL Server 2016 SSIS get cursor from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I am using SQL Server 2016.

1. I have a stored procedure `GET_RECORDS` that takes input parameters for filter and outputs a `CURSOR` parameter
2. I want to get this cursor in my SSIS package
3. I had created data flow task, OleDb source and variables for parameter values. Then mapped parameters

[Params mapping screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewRC.png)

but when I wanted to save the component - I got an error

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHcNy.png)

I tried to add clause `WITH RESULT SETS` with some dummy columns, but my procedure doesn't return any result set

What am I doing wrong?

Any advices will be helpful.

Thank you.

With regards, Yuriy.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to output a cursor.   is that something new in 2016, or is it just wishful thinking?

Comment: It is a requirement. I want to know is it possible to realize it)

Answer (score 0):

The source component is trying to determine what columns and types will be returned.  Because you are using dynamic SQL the metadata can change each time you run it.

With result sets allows you to define the data being returned but should only be used if you are guaranteed to have those results every time you execute.

EDIT:
I create a connection and run the command so that it populates a data table.  Then I put the column headers into a string array.  There are plenty of examples out there.

Then I use the following function to create a destination table.  Finally I create a datareader and pass that to the .Net SqlBulkCopy.  Hope this helps.

```
private void CreateTable(string TableName, string[] Fields)
        {                

            if (TableExists(TableName) && Overwrite)
            {
                SqlCommand = new SqlCommand($"Drop Table [{TableName}]", SqlConnection);
                SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            string Sql = $"Create Table [{TableName}] (";

            int ColumnNumber = 1;
            foreach (string Field in Fields)
            {
                string FieldValue = Field;
                if (! HasHeaders)
                {
                    FieldValue = "Column" + ColumnNumber;
                    ColumnNumber++;
                }
                Sql += $"[{FieldValue}] Varchar(8000),";
            }
            Sql = Sql + "ImportFileID Int, ID Int Identity(1,1) Not Null, Constraint [PK_" + TableName + "] Primary Key Clustered ([ID] Asc))";

            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Sql, SqlConnection);
            SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Joe.
Thank you for your answer.
In your example, there is one static table. But I am passing entity_name as input parameter to procedure, that's why I cannot set up static result set, because the result set depends of chosen entity table.
That's why I am trying to extract them as output parameter.
Maybe it will be better to output rowset instead of cursor?

With regards, Yuriy.

Comment: When I work with dynamic structures in SSIS I use a script task.  You might be able to use the API.  I will update my answer with a bit of c# code that I use when dynamically importing xls/csv.

Answer (score 0):

Use ado.net source instead of oledb source, define a simple select and get the columns you wish to return. Now you can define expresión in the dataflow properties.

Search ado.net source dynamic sql

:)

Comment: Could you explain this in a little more detail and how it is an answer to the question? Will it replace the need to return a `CURSOR`?

Answer (score 0):

try to return the records and  use foreach in ETL instead of cursor

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

I think you can do it from a simple way, but I don't know what you are you doing, exactly...